# C# Shorten if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I know this may be a very silly question but as a learner, I always like to learn new things.Anyway, here's a quick `If` statement :

```
string test = "It's a test";
string test2;
if (test != "")
{
    test2 = test;
}
else
{
    test2 = "It's null";
}
```

**Note: I'm aware that `Regex` can also be used to check if the string is empty: `Regex.IsMatch( "[A-TVWZ]", test)` . Also, I'm aware that I can use `SELECT CASE`**

In the code above, I am checking if `test` string is empty or not.If it is, then `test2` gets one value, if it's not,`test2` get's a different value.

My question is, is there a shorter/more elegant/quicker way to do it ? I mean one line which would check if string is empty or not and supply required value to `test2` ? I am aware that alternate solutions may take same execution time but was just wondering if there's one/two line code alternative for this ?

**To elaborate**

I want to check if a string is empty or not.For each cases, another string gets specific values...

Comment: you can `test != ""` and together with ternary operator: `test2 = test != "" ? test : "It's null";`

Comment: @GiladGreen , i am looking for a shorter alternative than `if` statement

Comment: An empty string is not the same thing as null.  Also what does quicker mean?  You don't get much "quicker" than an if statement checking a simple value

Comment: Your sample won't compile, because your braces are in the wrong place.

Comment: @Plutonix , no need to be hard here....I can ask you the same question if you want to use `regex` in some case instead of loops or it statements..... I asked because i wanted to know if there are any shorter alternatives

Comment: @zackraiyan what does regex have to do with anything?  What are you actually asking here?  Why aren't you using `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`?  I have so many questions...

Comment: Well, the only *shorter* version is provided in the answer. However internally it executes the exavt same code and thus isn´t faster - if that was the actual issue.

Comment: @zackraiyan you mention "quicker" in your question.  "quicker" is synonymous with "faster"

Comment: quicker stands for(or atleast i meant) a quick code .. such as one line regex can do a exactly what a 10 line for loop can do(in cases of strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
string test = "It's a test";
string test2 = (test != "") ? test : "0-length string";
```

Comment: How is this "quicker"?

Comment: It won't execute any quicker, but it is fewer lines of code, which seems to be what the question was about.

Comment: @maccettura because it initialised and declares at the same time?  p.s.  Use string.IsNullOrEmpty(string) because "" is ugly :P

Comment: I'm wondering why `test` is initialised early too... why not just have that inside the if itself?  Is it intended as a parameter?

Comment: @zackraiyan no,  I was just informing you, that you can simplify your logic.  Completely.   It's always better to avoid issues than make work arounds for them

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "It's a test";
var test2 = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(test)) ? test : "It's null";
```

Comment: Particularly for a newbie it helps if you provide a little explanation with your answer.  Here a little comment on the ternary operator would make your answer more useful.